# How to build a dataframe from values in a json string that is a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a giant list of values that I've downloaded and I want to build and insert them into a dataframe.

I thought it would be as easy as:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
records = giant list of dictionary

df['var1'] = records[0]['key1']
df['var2'] = records[0]['key2']
```

and I would get a dataframe such as

```
var1 var2
val1 val2
```

However, my dataframe appears to be empty?  I can individually print values from records no problem.

Simple Example:

```
t = [{'v1': 100, 'v2': 50}]
df['var1'] = t[0]['v1']
df['var2'] = t[0]['v2']
```

I would like to be:

```
var1 var2
100  50
```

Comment: how are really format you `record` can you post an example ? did you try `pd.DataFrame(your records here`) ?

Comment: added a simple example of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One entry of your list of dictionaries looks like something you'd pass to the `pd.Series` constructor.  You can turn that into a `pd.DataFrame` if you want to with the series method `pd.Series.to_frame`.  I transpose at the end because I assume you wanted the dictionary to represent one row.

```
pd.Series(t[0]).to_frame().T

    v1  v2
0  100  50
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas do exactly that for you !

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> t = [{'v1': 100, 'v2': 50}]
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(t)
>>> df
    v1  v2
0  100  50
```

**EDIT**

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> t = [{'v1': 100, 'v2': 50}]
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([t[0]['v1']], index=None, columns=['var1'])
>>> df
    0
0  100
```

Comment: Dang I gave you a bad example...There are theoretically hundreds of k, v pairs, and nested dictionaries. I am trying to build a dataframe with only selected values from the dictionary.

Comment: For instance, what it I only wanted 'v1' from t?

Comment: you mean `t[0]['v'1]` ?